# How to replace the '$' short cut

Tags: javascript, jquery, codepen

I have been working on this JS that when clicking on menu items the progress bar loads. I feel like it is pretty simple and I have even gotten it to work on codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ddaNQK

When I have tried to implement this code on my site I keep getting the error: 
"Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at (index):74"
I obviously still learning. So dumb down your answers a bit for me. How could I better write this code so that it will also work on my site?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".et_pb_tab_0").click(function() {
    $(".flyarrow")
      .removeClass("second third fourth fifth")
      .addClass("first");
  });
  $(".et_pb_tab_1").click(function() {
    $(".flyarrow")
      .removeClass("first third fourth fifth")
      .addClass("second");
  });
  $(".et_pb_tab_2").click(function() {
    $(".flyarrow")
      .removeClass("first second fourth fifth")
      .addClass("third");
  });
  $(".et_pb_tab_3").click(function() {
    $(".flyarrow")
      .removeClass("first second third fifth")
      .addClass("fourth");
  });
  $(".et_pb_tab_4").click(function() {
    $(".flyarrow")
      .removeClass("first second third fourth")
      .addClass("fifth");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.flyarrow,
.two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12vh;
  background: #ddd;
}

.arrow {
  display: block;
  height: 12vh;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00098e 0%, #49bca9 100%);
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
-webkit-transform: translate(-90%, 0px);
  transform: translate(-90%, 0px);
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border: 6vh solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid #49bca9;
}

.flyarrow.first .arrow {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-90%, 0px);
  transform: translate(-90%, 0px);
}

.flyarrow.second .arrow {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-80%, 0px);
  transform: translate(-80%, 0px);
}

.flyarrow.third .arrow {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-70%, 0px);
  transform: translate(-70%, 0px);
}

.flyarrow.fourth .arrow {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-60%, 0px);
  transform: translate(-60%, 0px);
}

.flyarrow.fifth .arrow {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
}

ul.et_pb_tabs_controls {
  background-color: rgba(0, 23, 43, 0.26);
  height: 12vh;
}

.et_pb_tabs_controls li {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="et_pb_tabs_controls">
 <li class="et_pb_tab_0">ONE</li>
  <li class="et_pb_tab_1">TWO</li>
  <li class="et_pb_tab_2">THREE</li>
  <li class="et_pb_tab_3">FOUR</li>
  <li class="et_pb_tab_4">FIVE</li>
    </ul>

<div class="flyarrow">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not related, just like Dog and Hotdog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the JQuery library prior to attempting to use it. Your CodePen has it referenced if you click the settings button and then the JavaScript tab.

Place this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in the `<head>` section of your document.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".et_pb_tab_0").click(function() {
    $(".flyarrow")
      .removeClass("second third fourth fifth")
      .addClass("first");
  });
  $(".et_pb_tab_1").click(function() {
    $(".flyarrow")
      .removeClass("first third fourth fifth")
      .addClass("second");
  });
  $(".et_pb_tab_2").click(function() {
    $(".flyarrow")
      .removeClass("first second fourth fifth")
      .addClass("third");
  });
  $(".et_pb_tab_3").click(function() {
    $(".flyarrow")
      .removeClass("first second third fifth")
      .addClass("fourth");
  });
  $(".et_pb_tab_4").click(function() {
    $(".flyarrow")
      .removeClass("first second third fourth")
      .addClass("fifth");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.flyarrow,
.two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12vh;
  background: #ddd;
}

.arrow {
  display: block;
  height: 12vh;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00098e 0%, #49bca9 100%);
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
-webkit-transform: translate(-90%, 0px);
  transform: translate(-90%, 0px);
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border: 6vh solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid #49bca9;
}

.flyarrow.first .arrow {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-90%, 0px);
  transform: translate(-90%, 0px);
}

.flyarrow.second .arrow {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-80%, 0px);
  transform: translate(-80%, 0px);
}

.flyarrow.third .arrow {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-70%, 0px);
  transform: translate(-70%, 0px);
}

.flyarrow.fourth .arrow {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-60%, 0px);
  transform: translate(-60%, 0px);
}

.flyarrow.fifth .arrow {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
}

ul.et_pb_tabs_controls {
  background-color: rgba(0, 23, 43, 0.26);
  height: 12vh;
}

.et_pb_tabs_controls li {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="et_pb_tabs_controls">
 <li class="et_pb_tab_0">ONE</li>
  <li class="et_pb_tab_1">TWO</li>
  <li class="et_pb_tab_2">THREE</li>
  <li class="et_pb_tab_3">FOUR</li>
  <li class="et_pb_tab_4">FIVE</li>
    </ul>

<div class="flyarrow">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This fixed it! Teach me just a little here, so is it common to reference JQuery like you suggested? or was there a way that I could have coded it better?

Comment: @AdamBaird This is standard JavaScript. You must reference external scripts before you attempt to use them. Otherwise, how would your browsers know anything about the script? Don’t forget to up vote the answer and mark it as the answer.